# Problem with FedEx Address validation web service

Tags: vb.net, validation, api, fedex

I'm trying to get started with Fedex'es Address validation service and I'm running into a road block with FedEx's own demo application.

This is the code in there app:

```
Sub Main()

    ''# Build a AddressValidationRequest object
    Dim request As AddressValidationRequest = New AddressValidationRequest()

    Console.WriteLine("--- Setting Credentials ---")
    request.WebAuthenticationDetail = New WebAuthenticationDetail()
    request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential = New WebAuthenticationCredential()
    request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Key = "###" ''# Replace "XXX" with the Key
    request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Password = "###" ''# Replace "XXX" with the Password

    Console.WriteLine("--- Setting Account Information ---")
    request.ClientDetail = New ClientDetail()
    request.ClientDetail.AccountNumber = "###" ''# Replace "XXX" with clients account number
    request.ClientDetail.MeterNumber = "###" ''# Replace "XXX" with clients meter number
    request.TransactionDetail = New TransactionDetail()
    request.TransactionDetail.CustomerTransactionId = "Address Validation v2 Request using VB.NET Sample Code" ''# This is just an echo back 
    request.Version = New VersionId()

    request.RequestTimestamp = DateTime.Now

    Console.WriteLine("--- Setting Validation Options ---")
    request.Options = New AddressValidationOptions()
    request.Options.CheckResidentialStatus = True
    request.Options.MaximumNumberOfMatches = 5
    request.Options.StreetAccuracy = AddressValidationAccuracyType.LOOSE
    request.Options.DirectionalAccuracy = AddressValidationAccuracyType.LOOSE
    request.Options.CompanyNameAccuracy = AddressValidationAccuracyType.LOOSE
    request.Options.ConvertToUpperCase = True
    request.Options.RecognizeAlternateCityNames = True
    request.Options.ReturnParsedElements = True

    Console.WriteLine("--- Address 1 ---")
    request.AddressesToValidate = New AddressToValidate(1) {New AddressToValidate(), New AddressToValidate()}
    request.AddressesToValidate(0).AddressId = "WTC"
    request.AddressesToValidate(0).Address = New Address()
    request.AddressesToValidate(0).Address.StreetLines = New String(0) {"10 FedEx Parkway"}
    request.AddressesToValidate(0).Address.PostalCode = "38017"
    request.AddressesToValidate(0).CompanyName = "FedEx Services"

    Console.WriteLine("--- Address 2 ---")
    request.AddressesToValidate(1).AddressId = "Kinkos"
    request.AddressesToValidate(1).Address = New Address()
    request.AddressesToValidate(1).Address.StreetLines = New String(0) {"50 N Front St"}
    request.AddressesToValidate(1).Address.PostalCode = "38103"
    request.AddressesToValidate(1).CompanyName = "FedEx Kinkos"

    Dim addressValidationService As AddressValidationService.AddressValidationService = New AddressValidationService.AddressValidationService
    ''#

    Try
        ''# This is the call to the web service passing in a AddressValidationRequest and returning a AddressValidationReply
        Console.WriteLine("--- Sending Request..... ---")
        Dim reply As New AddressValidationReply()
        reply = addressValidationService.addressValidation(request)


        Console.WriteLine("--- Processing request.... ---")
        ''#This is where I get the error 
        If (Not reply.HighestSeverity = NotificationSeverityType.ERROR) And (Not reply.HighestSeverity = NotificationSeverityType.FAILURE) Then
            If (Not reply.AddressResults Is Nothing) Then
                For Each result As AddressValidationResult In reply.AddressResults
                    Console.WriteLine("Address Id - " + result.AddressId)
                    Console.WriteLine("--- Proposed Details ---")
                    If (Not result.ProposedAddressDetails Is Nothing) Then
                        For Each detail As ProposedAddressDetail In result.ProposedAddressDetails
                            Console.WriteLine("Score - " + detail.Score)
                            Console.WriteLine("Address - " + detail.Address.StreetLines(0))
                            Console.WriteLine("          " + detail.Address.StateOrProvinceCode + " " + detail.Address.PostalCode + " " + detail.Address.CountryCode)
                            Console.WriteLine("Changes -")
                            For Each change As AddressValidationChangeType In detail.Changes
                                Console.WriteLine(change.ToString())
                            Next
                            Console.WriteLine("")
                        Next
                    End If
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                Next
            End If
        Else
            For Each notification As Notification In reply.Notifications
                Console.WriteLine(notification.Message)
            Next
        End If
    Catch e As SoapException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerText)
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit !")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

It *seems* to send the request object to the web service, but the"reply" object is returned with "Nothing". I could understand if I wrote the code, but good god... they can't even get their own code to work? Has anyone else seen/fixed this problem?

Comment: Have you updated the username, password, account number, and meter number as indicated? (And if so, you probably shouldn't share real credentials on a public site).

Answer (score 0):

The app shows some tell-tale signs of having been first written in C# and then converted to VB.Net later.  Specifically:

```
Dim request As AddressValidationRequest = New AddressValidationRequest()
```

Could be shortened to simply:

```
Dim request As New AddressValidationRequest()
```

.

```
If (Not reply.HighestSeverity = NotificationSeverityType.ERROR) And (Not reply.HighestSeverity = NotificationSeverityType.FAILURE) Then
```

could be written several ways, but at very least I would expect a pure-VB programmer to know of either `AndAlso` instead of `And` or `<>` instead of `Not ... = ...`.  Finally:

```
Dim reply As New AddressValidationReply()
reply = addressValidationService.addressValidation(request)
```

creates a new object and promptly discards it.

Comment: reply should be getting populated by the "addressValidationService.addressValidation(request)
" method based on the documentation I've read.